# Execute 2 SQL select statements at the same time and return the results as one set

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to return a timeline of data from various source tables and ideally I want the first statement to start executing at the same time as the last. Can this be done in SQL Management studio? 
Can I force the second and third select statement to run at the same time as the first?

```
SELECT ACTIVITY_DATE, ACTIVITY_TYPE
FROM TABLE_A

SELECT ACTIVITY_DATE, ACTIVITY_TYPE
FROM TABLE_B

SELECT ACTIVITY_DATE, ACTIVITY_TYPE
FROM TABLE_C
```

I'd probably out the results in separate CTE's and then combine them at the end to create the timeline of what happened when.

My expectation is taht this would take much less time tahn running the sequentially.

I've hunted for an answer and the closest I've seen is a method that creates and runs jobs on the fly but I can't see how I would get a dataset to work with later using that method.

Thanks to anybody that has a think about this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION` to combine the results if that's what you're after:

```
SELECT ACTIVITY_DATE, ACTIVITY_TYPE
FROM TABLE_A
UNION
SELECT ACTIVITY_DATE, ACTIVITY_TYPE
FROM TABLE_B
UNION
SELECT ACTIVITY_DATE, ACTIVITY_TYPE
FROM TABLE_C
```

This will return a single table with the results from each `SELECT` appended on to each other. It simply requires matching columns in each `SELECT`.

**Reference:**

### [UNION (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms180026.aspx)

> Combines the results of two or more queries into a single result set
>   that includes all the rows that belong to all queries in the union.
>   The UNION operation is different from using joins that combine columns
>   from two tables.
>
> The following are basic rules for combining the
>   result sets of two queries by using UNION:
>
> - The number and the order of
>     the columns must be the same in all queries.
> - The data types must be
>     compatible.

Comment: Folks - the key feature that I need is for all 3 queries to run at the same time. In a union they would still run sequentially. I want to save query time by hoitting 3 dfifferent tables at once and then combining the results later. APologies if that wasn't clear in my initial post.

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION` between your queries

```
SELECT ACTIVITY_DATE, ACTIVITY_TYPE
FROM TABLE_A

UNION

SELECT ACTIVITY_DATE, ACTIVITY_TYPE
FROM TABLE_B

UNION

SELECT ACTIVITY_DATE, ACTIVITY_TYPE
FROM TABLE_C
```

Comment: Folks - the key feature that I need is for all 3 queries to run at the same time. In a union they would still run sequentially. I want to save query time by hoitting 3 dfifferent tables at once and then combining the results later. APologies if that wasn't clear in my initial post.